# How to launch Chrome from node.js as a separate process and return immediately?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium

The objective is to launch Chrome or Chromium from nodejs using child_process, and return immediately, similar to how the windows START command launches a completely separate process and the calling process can exit immediately.

The { shell: true } option for child_process.execFile() almost does the job, in that it separates the node process from the Chrome process; I can exit the main nodejs process with Ctrl+C, and the launched browser remains open. Without that option, they remain married and ^C in node closes Chrome.exe.

What I need, however, is for node to exit completely after launching Chrome. There is apparently no adverse effects of pressing ^C. So if ^C is possible to exit node, why won't it exit immediately? I suspect until the chrome process object is destroyed, node can't exit in good conscience.

What is interesting: If the same Chrome.exe happens to be running already, the "new" Chrome I am launching starts a new tab or Window in that existing chrome and exits. In that case the nodejs script exits immediately.

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
let ex = "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Google\\Chrome\\APPLIC~1\\chrome.exe";

let chrome = child_process.execFile(ex, [
// tried various Chromium switches here but nothing helped
], {
    shell: true, // this spawns a separate process but node won't exit
} , function(err, data) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());
});

chrome.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

chrome.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

chrome.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
// chrome.kill();
});
```

Expected: Since the nodejs can be killed with ^C, why does it even continue running / blocking? I would expect it to exit after it launched Chrome.exe.

However, in actuality, nodejs blocks until I exit Chrome, or press ^C.

I also tried without callback function and .stdout, .stderr and .on hooks -- they don't seem to help or hurt. Node always blocks till I ^C or the child process, albeit separate, exits.

Comment: use `process.exit(0)` to exit your script with non-error. it doesn't exit immediately because there are running `EventEmitter`(s)

Comment: @r3wt works great thank you. I guess it feels a bit dirty; is there no official way to untangle the child process from the main process (remove the `EventEmitter`s), or even better, a way to start a process other than `child_process`, that is completely separate from the start? I tried to sneak in the `START` command in front of the executable path, as this is on Windows, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try my answer below. It works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Posting [r3wt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401804/r3wt)'s comment as answer here: use `process.exit(0)` to exit your script with non-error. it doesn't exit immediately because there are running `EventEmitter`(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

chrome = spawn(
    path.join(__dirname, '/path_to_chrome'), 
    [ ... your chrome switches here], 
    {
        shell: true,         // use to run in a shell if you need
        detached: true,      // important
        stdio: 'ignore'      // important
    }
);
chrome.unref(); // this one is important too
```

To achieve both: possibility to exit immediately and keep subprocess running, - follow the instructions below.

- Use `subProcess.unref()` which is [explained here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_unref)
  It prevents parent from waiting for a given subprocess to exit.
- One more [thing](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached) is `detached` option together with `stdio:'ignored'` which allow you to keep your subprocess alive even after you stop nodejs process.